# Change values of some fields based on conditions in multiple other fields in a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a general structure like this:

```
   60   700  701    702
0    1   40   40      1
1   40   40    1  10000
2   15   40   40  10000
3    1   40   40  10000
```

There are more columns (numbered from 1 to around 1500) and rows, but this captures the essence. I have a col_list, in this example  `col_list= [700, 701, 702]`. Now, I want to to set some fields to value 1 if the following conditions are met:

- Only rows where all fields with column numbers belonging to col_list have a value of either 40 or 10000.
- Only fields with column numbers belonging to col_list.
- Only fields with a value of 40.

So the result should look like this:

```
   60   700  701    702
0    1   40   40      1
1   40   40    1  10000
2   15    1    1  10000
3    1    1    1  10000
```

I've found a clunky way to do it with iterrows, but I really hope there's a more efficient and Pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

try via `loc`,`isin()` and `replace()`:

```
m=df[example].isin([10000,40]).all(1)
df.loc[m,example]=df.loc[m,example].replace(40,1)
```

**Note:** make sure the columns are of type int if they are of type string then use:

```
df.columns=[int(x) for x in df]
#df.columns=[int(x) if str(x).isnumeric() else x for x in df.columns]
```